# Specific Page Redirection to subdomain using .htaccess rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server

I want to redirect specific page url only to subdomain using .htaccess rule
**eg.-**
http://www.domain.com/blog **to** http://blog.domain.com/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://blog.subdomain.com/ [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(blog/.*)$ http://blog.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will take `www.domain.com/blog` and change it to `www.blog.domain.com`